# Cannot read property 'setNativeProps' of undefined react-native

Tags: react-native, native-base

i have used react-native-drawer . i have kept the side menu file seperate and import it in main file . i want to write click function in side menu file . when i click the first item it gives me this error. [image]

how can i solve this problem i think its mocking child component error .
here is my side menu file code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {

  View,
StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { Content,Text,List, ListItem . 
,Header,Icon,Left,Right,Body,Button,Title} from 'native-base';
import StatusComponent from './StatusComponent';
 import Hr from 'react-native-hr';

  export default class SideBar extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  console.log(props)
  asad=this.asad.bind(this);
    }
 asad(){
  alert('gata rhe ');


}
render(){
    return(

 <View style={{backgroundColor:'#262626',flex:1,
position:'relative' ,top:62}} >

    <List>
    <ListItem  >
      <Right>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.asad(this.props)}>          

        <Text style={{color:'white'}} > main page</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    </Right>
    </ListItem>

    <ListItem  >
      <Right>

          <TouchableHighlight >          

        <Text style={{color:'white'}} > secnd page</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    </Right>
    </ListItem>



   </List>

  </View>

    )
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution i m using NativeBase for ui things so touchable is not work in native listItems so i used button of native BAse like this

```
<ListItem Button onPress={() => this.asad(this.props) }  >
    <Right>
      <Text style={{color:'white'}} > page</Text>
    </Right>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

NativeBase provides help to include Drawer in our apps

Check [NativeBase Drawer](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Drawer)